# How can this be diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, positive-definite, hermitian-matrices

I read in a lecture note that a positive-definite hermitian n-by-n matrix A has a unique positive-definite square root B and get stuck in its proof of the uniqueness.Part of the proof goes as follows.

> Let B be a positive-definite square root of A. Then B commutes with A. Thus, B stabilizes each eigenspace of A. Since B is diagonalizable on V , it is diagonalizable on each eigenspace of A...

The "V" mentioned in the proof is the n-dimensional complex vector space where the matrix A acts as an operator.

I cannot figure out why *B is diagonalizable on V*.
Any help is welcomed!

Comment: How is $V$ defined? Is it the matrix of eigenvectors of $A$? If yes, then $A=VDV^T$ where D is diagonal and $B=VD^{0.5}V^T$ where $D^{0.5}$ means that every diagonal entry of $D$ was square-rooted

Comment: Unluckily not. It's the complex vector space.

Comment: Positive definite matrices are, by definition, self adjoint. Self adjoint matrices are always (orthogonally) diagonalizable.